# sqlite select by date C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is this the preferred/fastest way to select values after a certain date from a database:

```
SELECT name, creationDate FROM sometable WHERE date(creationDate) >= date('_date_in_sqlite_format_')
```

where `creationDate` is `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` type 
and `_date_in_sqlite_format_` is `'2007-01-01 10:00:00'` for example.

Is there a better way that can help sqlite engine process data faster?

The question is theoretical. I am aware that the query is not parameterized and/or follows more optimized programming conventions.

Comment: Use `creationDate` instead of `date(creationDate)`. Read about SARGable predicates.

Answer (score 0):

The `date()` function returns a value in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.
If you compare against a value that has the same format as the column values, you can make the comparison directly, which would allow optimization by using an index:

```sql
... WHERE creationDate >= '2008-01-01 00:00:00'
```